# moment timezone adjust timestamp to a timezone and return value

Tags: timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I try to modify timestamps timezone with moment-timezone and I want to get the modified value with the applied offset

```
var newTimestamp = momentTz.tz(timestamp, 'Europe/Berlin')
```

so here is what I try

```
    var results = {};

    for (var timestamp in timestamps) {
         var commitCount = timestamps[timestamp];
         console.log(typeof timestamp)
         console.log(timestamp)
         console.log(moment(timestamp).format())
         //console.log(moment.tz(timestamp, 'Europe/Berlin'))
         //results[ moment.tz(timestamp, 'Europe/Berlin')] = commitCount;
   };
```

here is a snippet from log

```
string
1528063200
Invalid date
```

How do I get the new timestamp?

Comment: What does `timestamp` look like?  What sort of output are you expecting?  Please give examples.  Also, is there a reason you have `momentTz` instead of just `moment`?

Comment: I already imported moment as `moment` and after all installed via npm `moment-timezone` so I had to gave another namespace

Comment: You don't need to do that.  Importing moment-timezone automatically imports moment.  One extends the other - don't import them both. 
 See [these docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/node-js/).  Also please give examples as asked, or I can't answer your question.  Thanks.

Comment: I made an update on post because my previous solution did not worked properly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `timestamp` values are strings that contain [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) values, in terms of seconds.  You can parse them with the `X` format specifier in moment.

However, you cannot get a timestamp in this format that is adjusted for a time zone.  That is because Unix Time values are *always* based on UTC.  It is nonsensical for them to be in a time zone.  Any such value would be in error.

You *can* however emit a string-based format, such as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - which is the default when you don't supply any arguments to the `format` function.

In short:

```
moment.tz('1528063200', 'X', 'Europe/Berlin').format() //=> '2018-06-04T00:00:00+02:00'
```